# Spring Cloud ZUUL - custom POST route filter

Tags: netflix-zuul

We are trying to write custom POST route filter for ZUUL. We are using Spring Cloud Zuul. This is what we are trying to do -

There are more than one instance of same service (ServiceA) registered with Eureka. We make a rest API request in ServiceA via ZUUL and the API is serviced by any one of the instances registered with Eureka. **What we want to know is the hostip of the instance which services that particulare request.**

We implemented a POST filter but the **RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRouteHost** is empty; is there any other way to get the hostip??

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
@Component
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        ctx.getResponseBody(); 
        ((IResponse) ctx.get("ribbonResponse")).getRequestedURI();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did but it says I need at least 15 reputation.

Comment: ohh. sorry, so just accept the aswer, I think it you can do